# Stop scaling a TGraphicControl component

Tags: delphi, scale, delphi-10.3-rio

This is my component constructor:

```
constructor TDiskMap.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(AOwner);
 FCellSize:= 13; FCellsH:= 10; FCellsV:= 10;
 Width:= (FCellsH * FCellSize) + 1;
 Height:= (FCellsV * FCellSize) + 1;
end;
```

When I run the application, the size of the control is not the one that I set in the constructor, because it is scaled after that. I want to take care myself of scaling and disable this autos-scaling, but TGraphicControl has no `Scaled` property. I tried to hook `WM_SIZW`, `WM_MINMAXINFO`, use Constrains... but no effect. Any ideas ?
I want that no one could automatically resize the control, except me. And I mean at the pixel level... regardless of dpi.

Comment: Do you want that **only this control** maintains num of pixels size or can you accept that its **parent is also fixed** or the **whole application**?

Comment: Just this control has to remain fixed in pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To react on scaling you need to override `ChangeScale` - to be precise, the three parameter overload of it.

If you don't want the default scaling behavior of the control you should avoid calling `inherited` in your derived method and handle all necessary calculations by yourself.

Note that this all is only valid when the application is dpi aware in the first place.